# My Web service didn't getting response on first attempt only and same web service works charm on other shared server

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I have created web services for one of my client, the web services didn't getting any response on first request and in second request its retrieved all required response data.

Same web services i have tried on  other server its works like charms giving me a proper response on time with all required data.

I don't figure out what the exact issue is ?
Need your precious suggestion.
thanks